# Quasar/Pulsar lein midje build errors on linux

Tags: java, clojure, pulsar, quasar

I am trying to install Pulsar. I have lein version

```
idf@idf-Satellite-C55t-A ~/Documents/clojure/pulsar $ lein version
Leiningen 2.5.0 on Java 1.7.0_72 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
idf@idf-Satellite-C55t-A ~/Documents/clojure/pulsar $
```

I have JAVA_HOME set

```
idf@idf-Satellite-C55t-A ~/Documents/java/quasar $ echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle
idf@idf-Satellite-C55t-A ~/Documents/java/quasar $
```

when I do a lein midje on the git cloned directory, I get a bunch of errors. Not sure what I am doing wrong? I suspect that is has to do with installing the java Quasar first correctly, but I am not certain.

```
idf@idf-Satellite-C55t-A ~/Documents/clojure/pulsar $ lein midje
...
above here no errors

QUASAR WARNING: Assertions enabled. This may harm performance.
Reflection warning, midje/util/ecosystem.clj:40:12 - call to java.io.File ctor can't be resolved.
Reflection warning, midje/clojure/core.clj:86:17 - reference to field hasRoot can't be resolved.
Reflection warning, midje/util/pile.clj:109:9 - call to contains can't be resolved.
Reflection warning, midje/config.clj:19:32 - call to contains can't be resolved.
Reflection warning, midje/emission/clojure_test_facade.clj:26:19 - reference to field toString can't be resolved.
Reflection warning, midje/parsing/util/file_position.clj:59:5 - reference to field getFileName can't be resolved.
Reflection warning, midje/data/metaconstant.clj:43:5 - reference to field getNamespace can't be resolved.
Reflection warning, midje/checking/checkers/chatty.clj:60:20 - call to java.lang.Error ctor can't be resolved.
Reflection warning, midje/checking/checkers/simple.clj:85:24 - reference to field throwable can't be resolved.
Reflection warning, midje/data/compendium.clj:60:38 - call to indexOf can't be resolved.
Reflection warning, midje/util/scheduling.clj:10:5 - call to cancel can't be resolved.
Reflection warning, dynapath/defaults.clj:13:52 - reference to field getURLs can't be resolved.
Reflection warning, dynapath/defaults.clj:27:28 - call to addURL can't be resolved.
Reflection warning, dynapath/util.clj:30:22 - reference to field getParent can't be resolved.
Reflection warning, midje/util/bultitude.clj:62:17 - reference to field canRead can't be resolved.
Reflection warning, midje/util/bultitude.clj:193:22 - call to replaceAll can't be resolved.
Reflection warning, midje/util/bultitude.clj:194:22 - call to replaceAll can't be resolved.
Reflection warning, clj_time/core.clj:577:10 - reference to field getDayOfMonth can't be resolved.
Reflection warning, midje/data/project_state.clj:25:18 - reference to field getName can't be resolved.
Reflection warning, midje/data/project_state.clj:26:28 - reference to field getName can't be resolved.
Reflection warning, midje/data/project_state.clj:49:24 - reference to field getPath can't be resolved.
Reflection warning, midje/data/project_state.clj:73:3 - reference to field lastModified can't be resolved.
Reflection warning, midje/repl.clj:103:12 - call to java.lang.Error ctor can't be resolved.
Reflection warning, midje/repl.clj:388:12 - reference to field getMessage can't be resolved.
Reflection warning, midje/repl.clj:391:50 - reference to field getMessage can't be resolved.
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Reflection warning, co/paralleluniverse/pulsar/actors.clj:737:7 - call to co.paralleluniverse.actors.behaviors.Supervisor$ChildSpec ctor can't be resolved.
Exception in Fiber "fiber-10000001" java.lang.Exception: my exception
    at co.paralleluniverse.pulsar.actors_test$eval9288$fn__9289$fn__9290$fn__9291$fn__9294.invoke(actors_test.clj:27)
    at co.paralleluniverse.pulsar.InstrumentedIFn.invoke(InstrumentedIFn.java:32)
    at co.paralleluniverse.pulsar.ClojureHelper.suspendableInvoke(ClojureHelper.java:183)
    at co.paralleluniverse.pulsar.ClojureHelper$3.run(ClojureHelper.java:170)
    at co.paralleluniverse.actors.PulsarActor.doRun(PulsarActor.java:90)
    at co.paralleluniverse.actors.Actor.run0(Actor.java:667)
    at co.paralleluniverse.actors.ActorRunner.run(ActorRunner.java:51)
    at co.paralleluniverse.actors.Actor.run(Actor.java:236)

and more errors...
```

So I downloaded the git repo of Quasar. First installing the system gradle using apt-get, and ran gradle inside the quasar directory. This gives me a different error:

```
idf@idf-Satellite-C55t-A ~/Documents/java/quasar $ gradle
sonatype username or password not set
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/ch/raffael/pegdown-doclet/pegdown-doclet/1.1.1/pegdown-doclet-1.1.1.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/pegdown/pegdown/1.2.1/pegdown-1.2.1.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/sourceforge/plantuml/plantuml/7968/plantuml-7968.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/parboiled/parboiled-java/1.1.4/parboiled-java-1.1.4.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/parboiled/parboiled-core/1.1.4/parboiled-core-1.1.4.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/ow2/asm/asm/4.1/asm-4.1.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/ow2/asm/asm-parent/4.1/asm-parent-4.1.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/ow2/asm/asm-tree/4.1/asm-tree-4.1.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/ow2/asm/asm-analysis/4.1/asm-analysis-4.1.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/ow2/asm/asm-util/4.1/asm-util-4.1.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/ch/raffael/pegdown-doclet/pegdown-doclet/1.1.1/pegdown-doclet-1.1.1.jar
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/parboiled/parboiled-core/1.1.4/parboiled-core-1.1.4.jar
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/ow2/asm/asm/4.1/asm-4.1.jar
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/ow2/asm/asm-tree/4.1/asm-tree-4.1.jar
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/ow2/asm/asm-analysis/4.1/asm-analysis-4.1.jar
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/ow2/asm/asm-util/4.1/asm-util-4.1.jar
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/parboiled/parboiled-java/1.1.4/parboiled-java-1.1.4.jar
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/pegdown/pegdown/1.2.1/pegdown-1.2.1.jar

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/home/idf/Documents/java/quasar/build.gradle' line: 185

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'quasar'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':quasar-actors:markdownDoclet'.
   > Artifact 'com.google.guava:guava:13.0.1@jar' not found.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 13.114 secs
idf@idf-Satellite-C55t-A ~/Documents/java/quasar $
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a legitimate test failure in the Pulsar project. Perhaps opening an [issue](https://github.com/puniverse/pulsar/issues?q=is%3Aopen%20is%3Aissue) on the github page will get things rolling. You do *not* need to build Quasar to use pulsar. ignore the slf4j logging errors if they don't bother you too much, or you can get rid of them easily with timbre

Comment: I asked on the users group and I was told this https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/quasar-pulsar-user/oiyi8Ro0gTw